# NameError: name 'loan_tape' is not defined when trying to call a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, nameerror

I receive a NameError (name 'loan tape' is not defined) when I try to execute the function.
What is wrong with the way the function is defined?

```
def create_table(table_name, num_rows, num_cols):
        table_name = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(num_rows,num_cols), columns = [["Exposure","EIR"]])
        return print(table_name.head(20))

(create_table(loan_tape ,20 ,2)
```

Comment: If this is all your code, then the error is right. There is not variable `loan_tape` defined.

Comment: Are you trying to have a dataframe initialised with the name "loan_tape"?

Comment: Where is he definition of your loan_type variable that you used in the function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing what I think - and that is trying to create a variable in advance and initialise it as a dataframe, then this is definitely not how you do it.

Pass 2 arguments, because that's all you need, and then `return table`.

```
def create_table(num_rows, num_cols):
    table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(num_rows,num_cols), 
                       columns=[["Exposure","EIR"]] 
           )

    return table.head(20)

loan_tape = create_table(20, 2)
print(loan_tape)

    Exposure       EIR
0   0.969132  0.379487
1   0.695092  0.787540
2   0.168266  0.989034
3   0.867826  0.499139
4   0.447891  0.922618
5   0.970134  0.252184
6   0.971446  0.049291
7   0.289744  0.797935
8   0.460266  0.176311
9   0.927201  0.280241
10  0.671764  0.520443
11  0.196516  0.258724
12  0.391544  0.190949
13  0.742233  0.590536
14  0.092953  0.558999
15  0.573201  0.505211
16  0.933630  0.656285
17  0.327771  0.264572
18  0.279868  0.527335
19  0.096123  0.560708
```

Note that you must not return `print(...)` because `print` returns `None`.

---

Edit: Passing `columns` as an argument:

```
def create_table(num_rows, num_cols, use_cols):
    table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(num_rows,num_cols), 
                       columns=use_cols)
    return table.head(20)

loan_tape = create_table(20, 2, [["Exposure","EIR"]] )
```

Comment: Precisely! Thanks a lot! One further question.How can I make the column names a list that you can input in the function arguments?

Comment: @PabloRodriguez Edited. Hope it helps.